# Image Viewer swipe vertically

Tags: codenameone

Is there any way to make Image Viewer swipe vertically? It would be great to have that functionality. If it's not implemented, is there any chance to achieve this overriding some method from the class?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

[The source](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/components/ImageViewer.java) assumes horizontal swipe quite heavily and this isn't trivial to change in a generic way as there is quite a lot of other code there to implement things such as pan and zoom.

You might be able to hack something manually that suits your needs based on our source. If you are able to come up with something generic and change the `ImageViewer` class feel free to [submit a pull request](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/how-to-use-the-codename-one-sources.html).

Comment: Ok, ok. I'll try something else. Thanks